# How do I make my app link send a person straight to my app page in google play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, url, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to make my link for my app send a user straight to the app store if he is using a android mobile device or give him the option to open it in the google play store whenever I send a user my url or link via text message or if he copy and pastes the link in his browser. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Firebase Dynamic Links** to create yuor own app url if a user has installed your app it will be opened; otherwise, it will redirect to your google play page